# Android Room Using generic field in Entity

Tags: android, generics, android-room

I am trying to use a generic field in a room entity:

```
@Entity
data class ConfigEntity<T>(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: String,
    val description: String,
    val targetType: String,
    val value: T
)
```

my question is - does room support this kind of field? If yes, how should i change the entity, or add to make it work?

at the moment, i am getting this error:

```
error: Cannot use unbound fields in entities.
    private final T value = null;
```

Comment: ¿Can you show your DAO class?

Comment: This class is part of a wrapper class that defines the generic types:
`
@Entity
data class ConfigEntityList(
      val someStringConfig: ConfigEntity<String>,
      val someIntConfig: ConfigEntity<String>
)
`
so the dao i need is related to the wrapper class, which is a simple dao of insert and get